# Elegant way to add user notes to queryset of articles in Django

Tags: python, django, django-custom-manager

Let's say I have such relation in Django.

[image]

Note model is used to store user notes for given in content_object article (or any other model). The point is to add notes field to all articles for currently logged user without creating method that will add notes field, eg.

```
for article in article_list:
    article.notes = Note.objects.get(author=self.request.user, content_object=article) 
# this is bad
```

For now I am trying to add note custom manager + generic relation in article.

#### Article.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
    notes = generic.GenericRelation(Note)
```

Note.py

```
class Note(models.Model):
      author = models.ForeignKey(User)
      ...
      objects = CustomManager()
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return super(CustomManager, self).get_query_set().filter(author=user)
```

This idea might work but only for all notes, I can't do this in template :(

#### template.html

```
{% for article in article_list %}
    {{ article.content }}
    {% for note in article.notes.for_user(user) %}
        {{ note.content }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<!-- where user is currently logged user !>
```

I am looking for an elegant way to "glue" user notes to article queryset, is there anything that can help me?

Comment: `QuerySet` has a method called `select_related` ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related ) - that will make the trick with selecting related `Notes` in a single query.
You can't call methods with an argument in a template - either change the logic that you dont need a parameter there (you already know that user in your View, where you create given QuerySet, right?) or use a TemplateTag

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko is something simmiliar to Book.objects.select_related('notes__author=bob') available? I am looking for function like select_related with restrictions (for example select related notes where note.author = logged_user)

Comment: What it that `Book` model now? But no, you cant do that :/ Have you look at its doc? `select_related` just says which table to join. To make constrations you have to use another method called `filter` so you have to combine them both: `Book.objects.filter(notes__author='Bob').selected_related('notes')` ( for example, idk how does your model `Book` look like)

Comment: Sorry, it was example from django docs, replace Book with Article ;) With filter method I am only able to select all Articles with notes that autor is 'Bob'. I need to get all articles and attach notes, the sql query would look like this
`SELECT a.id, a.content, (SELECT * FROM Note n WHERE n.content_object = a.id AND n.author='Bob') as notes FROM Article a`